# Notation for operations on vectors and matrices

Tags: matrices, notation, euclidean-geometry

I asked a question on the physics stack exchange site. [I was given the following answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53843/3d-get-linear-velocity-from-position-and-angular-velocity/53865?iemail=1#53865):

$$
  \dot{\vec r}(t) =\dot{\vec r}_0(t)+\vec \omega(t)\times (\vec r(t) - \vec r_0(t))
$$

Please could someone explain:

- What is meant by he dot and arrow over the letters (is it derivative and vector?)
- What type of operation the multiply sign represents (is it cross product?)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow means it's a vector. The dot is the derivative with respect to time. The multiply sign is the cross product.